# Converting htaccess rules to nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to convert my htaccess rules to nginx conf but i can't.

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^(ajax/|data/|js/|styles/|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?p=notfound [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Please give me some help with this code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to use an online converter :

http://winginx.com/en/htaccess

But cause i don't trust online converters try to read this :

http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2011/02/nginx-primer-2-from-apache-to-nginx/